# Fractional number as input. Code in floating-point or fixed-point?

Tags: floating-point, numbers, integer, fractions, fixed-point

I have a text-file with a bunch of fractional numbers(like +-1.8423) that I'm going to feed to my module to do some calculations with. The calculations are as follows:

```
temp1 = frac_num - integer_num
temp2 = temp1*temp1
```

What do I need in my port-declaration to take in this? And to do the previously mentioned operations on them.

Also, in the end this module is to work together with a c++ script, which operates on float-numbers. Would it be easier to implement the fore mentioned code directly with float numbers or to convert the float-numbers from the c-code to fixed point and then operate on these?

Comment: Generally, double will be faster and simpler than fixed point unless short decimal fractions have special significance. The classic case for fixed point is currency calculations.

Comment: What language is your module written in?
What do you mean by a port-declaration?
What do you mean by a C++ script?
What are your precision requirements and what range of numbers do you have?

In most cases double will be the correct answer. If double does not have sufficient accuracy (most non-integral numbers will be slightly rounded when converted to double) then you'll need something else.